# Setting Javac classpath

Tags: java

In the dev/proj/app/test.java file I have:

```
package proj.app;
...
import lib.sec.x;
...
```

In the /classes/proj/lib/sec I have x.class file.

When I try to compile java:

```
javac -classpath "/classes/proj/*" test.java
```

I got this error message:

```
package lib.sec does not exist
```

How to reference x.class file within classpath?

Answer (score 1):

The Java package is part of the (fully-qualified) class name. This

```
javac -classpath "/classes/proj/*" test.java
```

should be something like

```
javac -classpath "/classes:/classes/proj" proj/app/test.java
```

But your really shouldn't put `lib` (if it's a package name) under `proj` (a different package), the `lib` folder should be moved under `classes`. And then you only need `/classes` in the classpath.

Comment: Does it means javac should be run from within dev folder?